# Ansible 2.2 Create Postgresql Database

Tags: postgresql, ansible

I am new to ansible (2.2.1) and have started to migrate from our fabric scripts to ansible which I find somewhat better regarding structure. I have run into an issue, it should be pretty straight forward but since I do not know ansible through and through I am not sure how to proceed. I am running this against a **vagrant** box as of now.

The issue is regarding user privileges and postgres.

Lets say I have this playbook

```
- hosts: web
  become: yes
  become_user: root

  vars:
    dbname: myapp

  tasks:
  - name: ensure database is created
    postgresql_db: name={{dbname}}
```

I cannot make this simple example work! All dependencies are met. If I do the same thing with mysql this works fine but here I get issues with `unable to connect to database: FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "postgres"`. 
In mysql I use the "root" user with a blank password, which works because I know that user is created upon install with a blank password.

There is a user `postgres` created when the installation of postgresql is completed so the user exists. And as `root` I should be able to login by saying I am the `postgres` user. Am I missing something in how this is done? It works just fine if log into the server and `sudo -su postgres && psql`.

I also tried to add `become_user: postgres` by the task I want to run but then I get `unprivileged user` issues.

Any ideas of what is missing?

Comment: Your error is due to a Postgres config issue and not an Ansible issue.

Comment: I would not be that sure, considering I use a default installation of postgres from aptitude in this example as would all basic template playbooks featuring ansible and postgres_db module. So I do not believe that is the problem to be honest. Please do prove me wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a few workarounds and a solution, given you are ok with giving away some security (which makes sense, this being an issue just for that reason).

More people having this problem with the new ansible in this github issue thread
https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/16048

What I ended up doing was settings `allow_world_readable_tmpfiles = True` in the ansible.cfg file. Then this is not an issue anymore but you get warnings. I only need this setting for when handling the postgres role, so maybe I'll end up split it up or putting the setting somewhere less global.